# How to validate whether Element 2 occupied space left by the Element 1 using Selenium JAVA?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, compare

I got two box type elements : Element 1 and Element 2.

If Element 1 gets shrink then following element i.e Element 2 should occupy
left over space. Here Element 2 length is constant.

Element 1 xpath is `(//div[@class='site'])[1]`

Element 2 xpath is  `(//div[@class='site'])[2]`

How to validate whether Element 2 occupied space left by the Element 1?
Note: height is constant.

[image]

Here is the URL: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAINR.jpg

Comment: Are you sure the XPath mentioned in your question locates the web elements `Element 1` and `Element 2`? It looks like an image to me. If its an image, you may not be able to achieve what you are trying to. You may have to use OCR tools to read the image.

Comment: @Shawn Its webelements not image.

Comment: @Shawn
He is displaying to you what is on his website in picture style.

Answer (score 0):

First, you must determine the width of both elements. So, let's use this code to determine the width of both elements.

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("your website URL");

WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='site'])[1]"));
int width1 = element1.getSize().getWidth();

WebElement element2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='site'])[2]"));
int width2 = element2.getSize().getWidth();
```

Once you've determined the width of both elements, you should perform the shrink operation here.
You must obtain the width of both elements again after the shirks operation.

So let us use this code

```
int newWidth1 = element1.getSize().getWidth();
int newWidth2 = element2.getSize().getWidth();
```

Using the formulas "width1 > newWidth1" to determine whether the first element's new width is smaller than the original width and "newWidth2 == width2 + (width1 - newWidth1)" to determine whether the second element's new width has increased, we can determine that element 2 has taken up the space previously occupied by element 1.
So let's put the following in the if condition.

```
if (width1 > newWidth1 && newWidth2 == width2 + (width1 - newWidth1)) {
  System.out.println("Element 2 occupied the space left by Element 1");
} else {
  System.out.println("Element 2 did not occupy the space left by Element 1");
}
```

Comment: Second element width is same but **position** will be different after shrinking of first element. Can you modify your code?

Comment: But, in your example, the second element appears to have grown and taken over the first element's position, correct?

Comment: Oh you meant to say second move and occupies the first element without changing it's size?

Comment: you meant to say second move and occupies the first element without changing it's size? **YES!** Still Element 1 is present but it got pressed by element 2.

Comment: Okay, I don't know. May be some one else might help you.